# why @Formula always returns true when querying boolean from containing entity?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following JPA Entity called `Offer` that needs to derive it's `published` state from it's containing `ServiceItem` which has a `published` attribute (not formula) as well. `ServiceItem` `published` is `BIT` in the database table.

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Offer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @ManyToOne
    private ServiceItem serviceItem;

    @Formula("(select si.published from service_item si join offer o on si.id = o.service_item_id where o.id = id)")
    private boolean published;

}
```

The above formula returns always true for `Offer` no matter what is the `published` state of `ServiceItem`

It works correctly if I change the formula like that:

```
@Formula("(select case when si.published = true then true else false end from service_item si join offer o on si.id = o.service_item_id where o.id = id)")
```

what is wrong? Is it a bug or the expected behavior of `@Formula`s with booleans?

Comment: Formula actually needs to be a native query up to today if I‘m not mistaken.

Comment: both are native query indeed - am I missing something?

Comment: You are right! I‘m sure I saw a jpa query :) Which DB type is it? A bit could be a number. Probably the DB also supports booleans and there is no conversion in that case?

Comment: Changing `select field from table` to `select field = true from table` worked for me.